# Programatically trigger keydown event with `which` property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, keydown, onkeydown

How can I programatically trigger keydown event on Chrome that is going to have `which` property set to desired value?

tried

```
new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    'which':65,
    'charCode':65,
    'keyCode':65,
    'key':"a",
    'code':"KeyA",
});
```

but when receiving the property in input's `onKeyDown` handler, the event has `which,charCode and keyCode` equal to `0`. `key` is correctly set to `a`.

Comment: What is the full code?

Comment: Why is this necessary? Can't you just invoke the code that would have run if an actual `keydown` event was triggered with the `65` key?

Comment: This seems like a browser bug to me, given that `keyCode` is a documented part of the `KeyboardEvent` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, those event properties have default values of `0` and are not writable (due to their being deprecated). You have to delete the native properties and then re-create them:

```js
var ke = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    'key':"a",
    'code':"KeyA",
});

// Delete native event read-only properties with default values of 0
delete ke.keyCode;
delete ke.charCode;
delete ke.which;

// Create new custom properties that are read/write:
Object.defineProperty(ke, "keyCode", {"value" : 65});
Object.defineProperty(ke, "charCode", {"value" : 65});
Object.defineProperty(ke, "which", {"value" : 65});

var el = document.getElementById("key");

el.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){
  console.log(evt.key, evt.code, evt.keyCode, evt.charCode, evt.which);
});

el.dispatchEvent(ke);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="key">
```